# SSIS - Script Component pulling information from RabbitMQ

Tags: ssis, rabbitmq

A question that might be mostly theoretical, but I'd love to have my concerns put to rest (or confirmed).

I built a Script Component to pull data from RabbitMQ. On RabbitMQ, we basically set up a durable queue. This means messages will continue to be added to the queue, even when the server reboots. This construction allows us to periodically execute the package and grab all "new" messages since the last time we did so.

(We know RabbitMQ isn't set up to accommodate to this kind of scenario, but rather it expects there to be a constant listener to process messages. However, we are not comfortable having some task start when SQL Server starts, and pretty much running 24/7 to handle that, so we built something we can schedule to run every n minutes and empty the queue that way. If we'd not be able to run the task, we most likely are dealing with a failed SQL Server, and have different priorities).

The component sets up a connection, and then connects to the specific exchange + queue we are pulling messages from. Messages are in JSON format, so we deserialize the message into a class we defined in the script component.

For every message found, we disable auto-acknowledge, so we can process it and only acknowledge it once we're done with it (which ensures the message will be processed, and doesn't slip through). Then we de-serialize the message and push it onto the output buffer of the script component.

There's a few places things can go wrong, so we built a bunch of Try/Catch blocks in the code. However, seeing we're dealing with the queue aspect, and we need the information available to us, I'm wondering if someone can explain how/when a message that is sent to the output buffer is processed.

Is it batched up and then pushed? Is it sent straight away, and is the SSIS component perhaps not updating information back to SSIS in a timely fashion?

Would there be a chance for us to acknowledge a message, but that it somehow ends up not getting committed to our database, yet popped from the queue (as I think happens once a message is acknowledged)?